# Internet Explorer 11 WebDriver on WIndows 10 "Could not load IE WebDriver interface"

Tags: internet-explorer, webdriver

Currently there is no IE WebDriver for Windows 10. So I took files from "Windows8.1-KB2990999-x64.msu" and made side-by-side manifest for registration-free activation.

Now it opens empty browser window, and returns unknown error - "Could not load IE WebDriver interface".

[image: output]

Sample project here:
https://github.com/vsDizzy/WebDriver

Comment: Just checked it on Win 8.1 and got same error. So more likely it is registration issue.

Comment: The current version of the MS Edge FAQs suggest that Webdriver is not yet supported.  See http://dev.modern.ie/platform/faq/webdriver/ for details.  With luck, there will be an update soon.

Comment: Yes, but I wanted to start with IE11 first and when Edge WebDriver will be ready we will switch to it.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that the MS Edge team blog has a [new update on webdriver](http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/23/bringing-automated-testing-to-microsoft-edge-through-webdriver/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iewebdriver.dll needs to be registered via regsvr32

[image: output]

If we're using registration-free approach, then IE knows nothing about WebDriver installed and we have only one side of duplex channel. And that was the problem. )